# Domain vs Workgroup network speed

Tags: domain, workgroup

We have a small network (3 Win10 users and one headless Windows 2019 server as the DC and as a Network File Server). The normal advantages of a domain don't apply to my system (such as centralized management), and my system must cold start daily, and start up is faster and less error prone using workgroups.

So I demoted the DC and switched to a workgroup network. It all works fine except that we sometimes appear to have some problems that we didn't see on the Domain. Our investigation leads us to suspect network throughput issues, and possible some network storage issues.

So my questions is: Does a domain network handle network connections better than a workgroup network? For example, if I establish a TCP/IP socket connection between two computers, is there additional overhead on a workgroup network that would increase message latency, perhaps? Similar question with UDP broadcast, is there something about domain networks that makes data transfers more efficient than workgroups? Does a domain architecture establish some sort of trust with members that makes transfers and possibly file system access more efficient that you don't get on a workgroup architecture?

Comment: **What kind** of problems are you having?

Comment: Hi. We have distributed software with a lot of command and response interaction. The problem we have is a bottleneck somewhere meaning that we have queued buffers overflowing but it's difficult to isolate the root cause. I have reconfigured back and forth between Domain and Workgroup and Domain works better. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is that much difference in network speed.
The thing that is causing problem for you might be the authentication !

- In domain network when you are authenticated for first time, a ticket ( Token ) will be issued and you will be able to go and communicate with other machines or services without having to authenticate every time.
- But in a workgroup netwrok you should be authenticated every time you want to access something ( It might happen in background becuase your credential will be cahced in ram )

Any way my opinion is to use wireshark to see what is causing bottleneck

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I need to find the authentication traffic you mentioned.

Comment: your welcome ,If your problem is solved please close it otherwise please give more detail so we can help